# Php redis extended interger overflow

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

why? I guess is overflow,but i can't fix it.

```
<?php
/*redis*/
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1');
$res = $redis->eval('return   32140378*16777216');
var_dump($res);
exit;
//result：1509949440
//right：539226064027648
```

Comment: redis 64bit. redis eval is right. phpredis is wrong

Comment: @RyanVincent https://github.com/owlient/phpredis/pull/111 .php 64bit 5.4 ,redis 3.04, phpredis extend 2.2.7.   phpredis library.c reply_info is int change long long int and atoi change atol.I fix it.think you

Comment: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/pull/721 i fix it.think you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have repaired it myself, for more details: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/pull/721